# Redux: global state of props it isn't updated in between tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

In the project, the states of the props are managed globally with redux (redux-toolkit). So if I execute an action that modifies them, this should modify the global state and be taken in the rest of the tabs if I don't get it wrong.
It turns out that only when I refresh each tab it just takes the changes in the props but not "automatically", what can be caused this??

I best describe how it happens:

For example I have 2 tabs open, one where I add items to the cart and the other the cart. If I have 2 items in the cart and I delete them from right here, then I add another one from the items tab, it happens that in this it is not registered that the items were deleted and it appears to me as if I had added a 3rd item. If I go to the car and refresh, I get 3 items "having been added again" which I removed. If I now delete these 3 from the cart, I go back to the previous one and refresh, there it takes that they were deleted, being able to add articles from 0.

Also I thought that the reducer could be wrong since if I execute "addItem" action it should modify directly the current state of prop but I can't see an error here. Anyway happens what I described before.

This is my reducer slice:

```
// cart slice:
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
 
export const initialState = {
  items: [],
  countItems: 0,
 }
 
const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addItem: (state, action) => {
      const product = action.payload
      const itemExists = state.items.find((item) => product.id === item.id)
      if (itemExists) {
        itemExists.quantity += 1
      } else {
        const newProduct = { ...product, ...{ quantity: 1 } }
        state.items.push(newProduct)
      }
      state.countItems += 1
     
    },
    removeItem: (state, action) => {
      const product = action.payload
      state.items = state.items.filter((item) => product.id !== item.id)
 
      state.countItems -= product.quantity
    },
  },
})
 
export const {
  addItem,
  removeItem,
} = cartSlice.actions
export const cartSelector = (state) => state.cart
export default cartSlice.reducer
```

I would love any advice or hint about where I can find the mistake here, thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I'm using redux-persist to persist changes in store configured in root index.js as this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import App from './App'
import persistedReducer from './slices'
import {
  persistStore,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware({
    serializableCheck: {
      ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
    },
  }),
})
const persistor = persistStore(store)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure much about `redux-toolkit` library much. But to accomplish syncing between tabs not possible without using a persistent storage or a library that uses persists the global state. Here are a few options for you:

1. Using `session`/`localstorage` to store and retrieve your global state. This option requires you to set up your initial state whenever a new tab is being opened, along with serialization/deserialization (`JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`) is required.
2. [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist). This library comes with a lot of features out of the box but at the same time, it requires a bit more configurations. It'll do serialization/deserialization on behalf of you. One of the main pain points is it's not updated frequently so may introduce a lot of vulnerabilities.
3. [Web workers](https://github.com/aohua/redux-state-sync) (i.e. [redux-state-sync](https://github.com/aohua/redux-state-sync) library). Less configuration
4. [IndexDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) (i.e. [pouchdb](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb) and [react-pouchdb](https://github.com/ArnoSaine/react-pouchdb)) Example using [pouchdb](https://arnosaine.github.io/react-pouchdb/).

[Here](https://medium.com/@daverivera90/sharing-state-between-browser-tabs-with-redux-68899eb88fb7) is a blog post that explains these in much more detail.

Comment: I'm using redux-persist, I forget to say that. But I've no heard about redux-state-sync, it sounds like it could solve my issue. I'll take a look and tell you if works... thank you very much!

Comment: Solutions N°2 works for me... It happens that I have redux-persist already setted, but it  must be configured in a proper way to achive this... like is explained in this guide. I'm happy :)